# what is the regular expression to extract second path segment of a URI?

Tags: c, regex, posix-ere

I need to extract only the second path segment of a URI i.e. given the following URI:

```
/first/second/third/fourth/...
```

the regex should extract the `second` string from the URI. An explanation of the solution regex would be greatly appreciated.

I am using POSIX complaint regex library.

**EDIT:**
The solution given by Gumbo works at [REtester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

But, it doesn't seem to work with the code below:

```
#include "regex.h"
char *regexp (const char *string, const char *patrn, int *begin, int *end){     
        int i, w=0, len;                  
        char *word = NULL;
        regex_t rgT;
        regmatch_t match;
        wsregcomp(&rgT,patrn,REG_EXTENDED);
        if ((wsregexec(&rgT,string,1,&match,0)) == 0) {
                *begin = (int)match.rm_so;
                *end = (int)match.rm_eo;
                len = *end-*begin;
                word = (char*) malloc(len+1);
                for (i=*begin; i<*end; i++) {
                        word[w] = string[i];
                        w++; }
                word[w]=0;
        }
        wsregfree(&rgT);
        return word;
}

int main(){
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;

    char *word = regexp("/first/second/third","^/[^/]+/([^/]*)",&begin,&end);
    printf("ENV %s\n",word);
}
```

The above prints `/first/second` instead of only `second`

**EDIT2:**
Same result with `java.util.regex` as well.

Comment: These parts are called *path segments*.

Comment: Complaint? Don’t you rather mean *compliant*? But compliant to POSIX BRE or POSIX ERE?

Comment: @Gumbo - Yes it is compliant and not complaint. Not sure if it is BRE or ERE but regex.h says "Implements POSIX draft P10003.2/D11.2"

Comment: @Suresh Kumar: I think that is POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax.

Comment: @Gumbo - You are right, it is ERE. What should I change to get the second path segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re just having an absolute URI path, then this regular expression should do it:

```
^/[^/]+/([^/]*)
```

An explanation:

- **`^/`** matches the start of the string followed by a literal `/`
- **`[^/]+/`** matches one or more characters except `/`, followed by a literal `/`
- **`([^/]*)`** matches zero or more characters except `/`.

The second path segment is then matched by the first group. I used `+` for the first and `*` for the second because if the first would also allow a zero length, it wouldn’t be an absolute path any more but a scheme-less URI.

Comment: He also asked for an explaination

Comment: Your solution seems to work with RETester but not with code above (see question)